# How do I find the largest integer fully supported by hardware arithmetics?

Tags: c++, math, arbitrary-precision

I am implementing a BigInt class that must support arbitrary-precision operations on integers.

Quote from "The Algorithm Design Manual" by S.Skiena:

> *What base should I do* [editor's note: arbitrary-precision] *arithmetic in?* - It is perhaps simplest to implement your own high-precision arithmetic package in decimal, and thus represent each integer as a string of base-10 digits. However, it is far more efficient to use a higher base, ideally equal to the square root of the largest integer supported fully by hardware arithmetic.

How do I find *the largest integer supported fully by hardware arithmetic*? If I understand correctly, being my machine an x64 based PC, the largest integer *supported* should be 2^64 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 - Architectural features: 64-bit integer capability), so I should use base 2^32, but is there a way in c++ to get this size programmatically so I can typedef my base_type to it?

Comment: Square root of 64 is 32?  I thought it was 8.

Comment: It's sqrt(2^64) = 2^32 I will edit post to make it clearer

Comment: No problem, it was plain wrong by the way, not just obscure... thank you.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert I know I compile code to a specific processor, indeed I asked this question to make my code use the right sized type for each processor it will be compiled on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` (and, by extension, `unsigned int`) is the "natural" size for the architecture. So a type that has half the bits of an int should work reasonably well. Beyond that, you really need to configure for the particular hardware; the type of the storage unit and the type of the calculation unit should be typedefs in a header and their type selected to match the particular processor. Typically you'd make this selection after running some speed tests.

INT_MAX doesn't help here; it tells you the largest value that can be stored in an int, which may or may not be the largest value that the hardware can support directly. Similarly, INTMAX_MAX is no help, either; it tells you the largest value that can be stored as an integral type, but doesn't tell you whether operations on such a value can be done in hardware or require software emulation.

Back in the olden days, the rule of thumb was that operations on ints were done directly in hardware, and operations on longs were done as multiple integer operations, so operations on longs were much slower than operations on ints. That's no longer a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I understand that I cannot count on INT_MAX and INTMAX_MAX. Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 64-bit integer capability is listed as one of the architectural features of x86-64 processor, so I assume in my case I should use a 32 bit type to store, and a 64 bit type for operations, but I will have to confirm that with speed tests. In my implementation sizeof int and long is 4, while sizeof long long is 8 so I would typedef int store_t; typedef long long calc_t; or, probably just: typedef int32_t store_t; typedef int64_t calc_t; Do you think my approach would be correct now?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia - your life will be much simpler if you use unsigned types. I've written large integer packages for Java and for C++. Java doesn't do unsigned, and the code is constantly masking off the high bit. C++, with unsigned types, came together much faster (in fairness, that was the second time I'd done it; but not having to mask out those bits was a great help)

Comment: I think this is wrong.  The standard says `int` is the "natural" size for the architecture - but I would argue that for x64 compilers that would make `int` 64 bits (it's the register size) - but in practice, all such compilers use 32 bit ints.

Answer (score 5):

You might be searching for `std::uintmax_t` and `std::intmax_t`.

Comment: I guess INTMAX_MAX is actually what I was looking for. I think I will have to find the type that fits sqrt(INTMAX_MAX) and use it to store my BigInt digits.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia - INTMAX_MAX doesn't tell you what the largest hardware type is. It tells you what the largest integral type is. It will typically be long long, but there is no requirement that long long be supported in hardware; it can be done through emulation.

Comment: @PeteBecker indeed, I did not mention it but `uintmax_t` might be implemented by the compiler. If I am not mistaken, nothing in the standard is about the largest integer type supported by the hardware.

Comment: @mpu - yes, I've said that several times. Since the question asks for the largest integer type **supported fully by hardware arithmetics**, none of the mechanisms for determining the largest value of any particular type helps.

Answer (score 2):

`static_cast<unsigned>(-1)` is the max int. e.g. all bits set to `1` Is that what you are looking for ?

You can also use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` or `UINT_MAX`, and all of these will yield the same result. and what these values tell is the maximum capacity of `unsigned` type.  e.g. the maximum value that can be stored into unsigned type.

Comment: You reply on two's complement here, but I'm not sure its in the question's generality.

Comment: @Neel Sorry I don't have the knowledge to judge if your answer and mpu's one are equally good but his uses the standard so I chose that.

Comment: No Problem ... also check the updated answer. I've added more alternatives.

Comment: Looking at the alternatives I can see there is a problem with your answer. You are suggesting me to use the maximum capacity of unsigned type, while I am looking for maximum value of an object of the maximum width integer type (supported by implementation).

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` or `INT_MAX` will give you the maximum value of `int` type.

Comment: @Dani:  He relies on the standard's definition of `unsigned`.

Comment: This tells you the maximum value of `unsigned`, but the OP wanted to know the largest of `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, and `uintmax_t` ***which is supported in hardware***.

Answer (score 1):

Things are not so black and white. There are MAY issues here, and you may have other things worth considering. I've now written two variable precision tools (in MATLAB, [VPI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) and [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class-currently-in-beta-release)) and I've chosen different approaches in each. It also matters whether you are writing an integer form or a high precision floating point form.

The difference is, integers can grow without bound in the number of digits. But if you are doing a floating point implementation with a user specified number of digits, you always know the number of digits in the mantissa. This is fixed.

First of all, it is simplest to use a single integer for each decimal digit. This makes many things work nicely, so I/O is easy. It is a bit inefficient in terms of storage though. Adds and subtracts are easy though. And if you use integers for each digit, then multiplies are even easy. In MATLAB for example, conv is pretty fast, though it is still O(n^2). I think gmp uses an fft multiply, so faster yet.

But assuming you use a basic conv multiply, then you need to worry about overflows for numbers with a huge number of digits. For example, suppose I store decimal digits as 8 bit signed integers. Using conv, followed by carries, I can do a multiply. For example, suppose I have the number 9999.

```
N = repmat(9,1,4)
N =
     9     9     9     9

conv(N,N)
ans =
    81   162   243   324   243   162    81
```

Thus even to form the product 9999*9999, I'd need to be careful as the digits will overflow an 8 bit signed integer. If I'm using 16 bit integers to accumulate the convolution products, then a multiply between a pair of 1000 digits integers can cause an overflow.

```
N = repmat(9,1,1000);
max(conv(N,N))
ans =
       81000
```

So if you are worried about the possibility of millions of digits, you need to watch out.

One alternative is to use what I call migits, essentially working in a higher base than 10. Thus by using base 1000000 and doubles to store the elements, I can store 6 decimal digits per element. A convolution will still cause overflows for larger numbers though.

```
N = repmat(999999,1,10000);
log2(max(conv(N,N)))
ans =
       53.151
```

Thus a convolution between two sets of base 1000000 migits that are 10000 migits in length (60000 decimal digits) will overflow the point where a double cannot represent an integer exactly.

So again, if you will use numbers with millions of digits, beware. A nice thing about the use of a higher base of migits with a convolution based multiply is since the conv operation is O(n^2), then going from base 10 to base 100 gives you a 4-1 speedup. Going to base 1000 yields a 9-1 speedup in the convolutions.

Finally, the use of a base other than 10 as migits makes it logical to implement guard digits (for floats.) In floating point arithmetic, you should never trust the least significant bits of a computation, so it makes sense to keep a few digits hidden in the shadows. So when I wrote my [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class-currently-in-beta-release) tool, I gave the user control of how many digits would be carried along. This is not an issue for integers of course.

There are many other issues. I discuss them in the docs carried with those tools.

Comment: I am implementing a BigInt class to handle arbitrary-precision operations on integers. I updated question to reflect this.